# how to find out where in the RSOP a GPO registry change occured

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm following this document:

http://blog.unidesk.com/gpos-set-custom-registry-entries-virtual-desktops-disabling-machine-password

In the instruction, it shows how to change a GPO Registry.
[image]

My problem is the target computers.  How do I view the Registry GPO changes in the RSOP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use RSOP.  Use `gpresult /h gpresult.html`.

[image]

Comment: sorry....windows server 2003.  /h is not valid.  is there another option?